# How do you say self-loathing and self-pity in Ukrainian? What is the translation?

Tags: переклад, from-english, from-german

Can you translate "self-loathing" with one or two words in Ukrainian?

There's nothing on [e2u.org.ua](http://e2u.org.ua), [yenotes.com](http://yenotes.com), and even on lingvo that I don't trust too much.

Can I translate it as a term and not as "ненависть до себе" ([Google](https://translate.google.com/?hl=uk#en/uk/self-loathing) shows "самовідчуття", which is clearly wrong (as it is not feeling but loathing) and "ненависть до себе",) as the latter is far too long (6 syllables instead of 4, 3 words instead of 1 or technically 2)?

As I'm actually translating from German (Selbstmitleid), I also tried self-pity, and it's the same:

[e2u.org.ua](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=self-pity&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on):

> жалість до самого себе

[lingvo](https://www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/en-uk/self-pity):

> жалість до (самого) себе, схильність нарікати на долю

I desperately need something shorter and more precise in translation.

Would "саможаління" or "саможалощі" be a proper Ukrainian word?

Comment: "нитик" на мій погляд підходить якнайкраще.

Comment: @AlexSodin  я питаю про процес, не про людину, яка перебуває в цьому процесі. До того ж, нити, ниття - не терміни, більш розмовні слова.

Comment: в такому випадку - "ниття"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спочатку розберемося з тим, що треба перекласти.

> [Self](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/self_2)- is used to form words which indicate that you do something
>   to yourself or by yourself.
>
> [loathe](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/loathe) - If you loathe something or someone, you dislike them
>   very much.
>
> [Loathing](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/loathing) - is a feeling of great dislike and disgust.
>
> If someone feels [self-loathing](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/self-loathing), they feel great dislike and disgust
>   for themselves.

Знаходимо відповідник зі словника.

> [Сам](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC) - Уживається для позначення особи, яка діє, виконує щось
>   особисто.
>
> [Зневага](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0) - цілковита байдужість до кого-, чого-небудь, відсутність
>   турботи, піклування про когось, щось.
>
> [Самозневага](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0) - зневага до самого себе.

Від себе додам, що варто звернути увагу на [складні слова](https://r2u.org.ua/pravopys/pravXXI/28.html). Не думаю, що усі складні слова прописані у словниках. Їх можна, в залежності від змісту, підібрати дуже і дуже багато. Наприклад, самонелюбов, самоогида (disgust - огида), самообрида, самовідраза які теж можуть збігатися за значенням.

Comment: Спочатку не дуже уважно прочитав відповідь, а тепер бачу, що вона досить узагальнює варіанти. Радо її приймаю.

Answer (score 5):

If someone feels **self-loathing**, they feel great *dislike* and *disgust* for themselves. Жалість до самого себе is not the same thing. It means self-pity. As for схильність нарікати на долю, it's not what you are looking for either, because if someone complains a lot, it doesn't mean they feel great dislike and disgust for themselves.

Interestingly, [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selbstmitleid) says that **Selbstmitleid** is self-pity in English and жалость к себе or саможаление in Russian. So, it your original word is Selbstmitleid, I think you can use жалість до самого себе / саможаління.

If you were translating from English and your original word was "self-loathing", I'd suggest ненависть до себе.

Comment: The problem is, I don't see саможаління in sum.in.ua or any other dictionary. How comes?

Comment: @P.Vovk hm... perhaps, it's considered to be non-standard Ukrainian... I don't see any other explanation. In this case, жалість до самого себе will do the job.

Comment: "жалість до самого себе" is four words, I was looking for sth shorter than that. Would it be all right to use "саможаління"? Αs people do use it [on the web](https://goo.gl/CRvzTm), I'm just not sure if it's correct.